# Brightness keys adjust brightness too many times

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-netbook, brightness, acer

Every time I hit a brightness key on my laptop's keyboard, it adjusts the brightness by three steps instead of one. How can I fix it so that it only adjusts one step at a time?

I am using an Acer Aspire D250 with the newest firmware. It was working better when I was using Ubuntu 10.10 with older firmware (although the scale was off).

Any tips on debugging this would be appreciated.

**Edit:** My graphics:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)`

```
/sys/class/backlight$ ls
acpi_video0  intel_backlight
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a smiliar problem:

> I run Ubuntu 12.04 on my netbook (Acer Aspire One D255E) and I have
>   the following problem with the brightness settings: If I want to
>   adjust the brightness with the fn-key, I can only change between three
>   brightness steps, but my netbook has nine brightness steps.

Ruben Bakker gave this instructions, which solved the problem.

> Easy fix. In the terminal:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> You will find this line in the new opened window:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> Change it to:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
> ```
>
> Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Then reboot. Rejoice :)

Link:
[Problem with brightness settings with Acer Aspire One D255E in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172722/problem-with-brightness-settings-with-acer-aspire-one-d255e-in-12-04)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Worse still, my screen stayed black after wakeup.

Answer (score 0):

Put '**blacklist video**' (without the quotes) in

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and reboot. Hopefully this should solve your problem.

Comment: No, blacklisting video didn't do anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
# rmmod video
# modprobe video brightness_switch_enabled=0
```

Comment: What is this for? The answer is incomplete. Please post all the steps, start to finish, so new users can understand.

Comment: @RickGreen-Turbo This canned comment is never appropriate when posted in response to *an answer*. The linked meta question is not saying to avoid posting incomplete answers *as answers* (and it is even sometimes appropriate to do so). It's saying to avoid posting them as *comments*.