# Problem with brightness settings with Acer Aspire One D255E in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, brightness, acer

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on my netbook (Acer Aspire One D255E) and I have the following problem with the brightness settings: If I want to adjust the brightness with the fn-key, I can only change between three brightness steps, but my netbook has nine brightness steps.

If I adjust the brightness in the system settings, it works fine and I can choose between nine steps, so I know they are there. They are just jumped, when I use the fn-keys. The funny thing: If I click the fn-key like crazy, I can get to the steps between, too. Does anybody have an idea, what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Comment: This also fixes the Brightness not being maximum at boot on Acer Aspire Happy 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy fix. In the terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You will find this line in the new opened window:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot. Rejoice :)